# How to add an extra button above the TouchScreenKeyboard in UIInput NGUI?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

My game uses a registration form scene in order to register a user. I've got several Textboxes(UIInput) on screen.

I would like to have Next/Previous Button over the keyboard which appears when i select a text box for input. this way i will be able to navigate on multiple textboxes in the registration form.

right now i am using HideInput=true so there is nothing over the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have Box Collider "using UIInput",
 Simple way would be to add UIButton To your InputBox.

Once you do that attach scene GameObject or PrefabObject, with a public method() to the UIButton OnClick Notify option, Select Method from the drop down.

Test Code:

```
Private Bool ShwNxtBtn = false;

 Public Void MethodName(){
  if (ShwNxtBtn != true){
      ShwNxtBtn = true;
   }else{
     ShwNxtBtn = false;
}
```

Note: you could use Toggle, but I've had some issue with that and input Collider.

Comment: Apologies if i couldn't explain my question well enough. actually the appearing keyboard is not created in unity. as you know, if you start typing in UIInput textbox, a native keyboard appears just like any iOS UITextfield. i need to add an extra button on the native/device touch-keyboard.

Comment: Or may be i was unable to understand your answer here.